# Drawing a Bitmap with a Arduino UNO onto a SSD1351 OLED

Tags: c, arduino

I wanted to write a Bitmap array interpreter, while using the "ucglib" library, for my SSD1351 OLED Display, while using a Arduino UNO as the controller. My problem is that the picture that is being shown on my display, is just a mess of colors, while the bitmap array is just a pure red color.
I am converting my PNG with these conversion settings:

- preset name: Color R5G6B5
- data block size: 16 bit(s), uint16_t
- RLE compression enabled: no
- conversion type: Custom, not_used not_used
- split to rows: yes
- bits per pixel: 16
- 
- preprocess:
- main scan direction: top_to_bottom
- line scan direction: forward
- inverse: no

This is my Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Ucglib.h"

Ucglib_SSD1351_18x128x128_SWSPI ucg(/*sclk=*/ 13, /*data=*/ 11, /*cd=*/ 7, /*cs=*/ 10, /*reset=*/ 8);
    
static const uint16_t image_data_fcb[8192] PROGMEM = {

    0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8,
    0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000,
    0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8,
    0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000,
    0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8, 0x0000, 0x00f8,
    *shortened for the sake of readability*};

void RGBBitmap(uint8_t height, uint8_t width, const uint16_t bitmap[]) {
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      uint16_t color = bitmap[y * width + x];

      Serial.print("Color at ");
      Serial.print(x);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(y);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(color, HEX);

      // Extracting RGB components
      uint8_t red = ((color >> 11) & 0x1F) << 3;
      uint8_t green = ((color >> 5) & 0x3F) << 2;
      uint8_t blue = (color & 0x1F) << 3;

      // Map the components to a desired color format
      // (in this case, using ucg.setColor function)
      ucg.setColor(red, green, blue);

      // Draw the pixel on the display
      ucg.drawPixel(x, y);
    }
  }
}

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communication
  delay(1000);
  ucg.begin(UCG_FONT_MODE_NONE);
  ucg.clearScreen();

  RGBBitmap(64, 64, image_data_fcb);
  Serial.println("Setup completed");

  //ucg.clearScreen();

}

void loop(void) {
  
}
```

I tried changing my bitshifting, i tried using a different color extraction method, i tried changing my conversion settings but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your `image_data_fcb` looks like 32 bits per pixel, not 16.

Comment: Also you can't access `PROGMEM` data like regular data in RAM. It's located in flash address space, so you should use [special functions](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is code and logic that successfully extracts BGR color channels from 16 bit and 15 bit color images; both these image formats are using 16 bit ints to store a single pixel.

Please note that this code applies the mask 1st, and *then* shifts the bits right.

That order of operations is not always 100% mandatory, if ever.  As for the code in your question, I note that it shifts right first, *and then* applies masks.  By itself, this ordering is not an issue.

The trouble I think is that the code you're using does a *shift left as a last step*:

```
uint8_t red = ((color >> 11) & 0x1F) << 3; /* Final '<< 3' is suspect */
```

This last shift operation leaves the color bits in the *high bits* of the 8 bit byte.

Conversely -- the code below leaves the color bits in the very lowest bits of the 8 bit byte.  Confidence is high that this placement of bits should resolve the issue.

I have included an additional 15 bit image routine just in case.  I have seen images presented as 16 bit color when they were actually 15 bit, and that can be a problem.  Nice to have both to try, I figure.

Runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/obaWe346f) so you can see that this code is compile-able, workable.

```
/*------------------------------------------
 16 bit:    RRRRRGGG GGGBBBBB
    Color   Binary field view   Hex mask
    RED  :  11111000 00000000   (0xF800)
    GREEN:  00000111 11100000   (0x7E0)
    BLUE :  00000000 00011111   (0x1F)

Extract 16 bit to BGR:
Where w is the 16 bit int having a 16 bit image pixel:
*------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t RED =     ((w)&0xF800)>>11;
uint8_t GREEN =   ((w)&0x7E0)>>5;
uint8_t BLUE =    ((w)&0x1F);

/*------------------------------------------
 15 bit:    xRRRRRGG GGGBBBBB
    Color   Binary field view   Hex mask
    RED  :  01111100 00000000   (0x7C00)
    GREEN:  00000011 11100000   (0x3E0)
    BLUE :  00000000 00011111   (0x1F)

Extract 15 bit to BGR:
Where w is the 16 bit int having a 15 bit image pixel:
*------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t RED =     ((w)&0x7C00)>>10;
uint8_t GREEN =   ((w)&0x3E0)>>5;
uint8_t BLUE =    ((w)&0x1F);
```

Comment: @OMEGA_F  -- please tell me if my answer helped, or if you have any questions about it - thx

Comment: @OMEGA_F -- thanks for getting back to me, understood.   Well, unpacking any color bit format is really not hard and fun for me.  The only hurdle we both face is: where are the red, blue and green bits in that 16bit (uint16_t ) color pixel?  I mean, is red in the high five bits?  Or middle 6 bits? ... we can lose a lot of time by guessing.  I'm thinking somewhere in the documentation, it must say the details of the pixel returned by pgm_read_byte_near() -- which is a macro I think?  -------- Once we have that info, success should be a short walk away.  ;-)

Comment: I will check and get back to you, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @OMEGA_F -- Also, looking closer at your image date ```uint16_t image_data_fcb```  i think dimich was right -- it *does* look like 32 bit image data.
See how it repeats? 0xF8, then 0x0, then repeat, repeat.  Each of those are 16 bits, and 0XF8 and 0x0 probably form one pixel -- for a 32 bit pixel!   
And *that* means that maybe you should be using pgm_read_dword_far() -- or whatever you use to read 32bit values from memory.   (maybe -- i'm not expert on Arduino)

Comment: Omg, i have it. The problem was not the library, as i had stated earlier, i had just misinterpreted the code. The problem was that "pgm_read_byte_near" only read, for example, the "08" in "0x4208", but now i have used "pgm_read_dword" and it now reads the whole hexadecimal number. As a result it never extracted the right "rgb" values. And thanks to your help with the color extraction it now works perfectly. :D
Thank you for your extensive answers, i greatly appreciate it :D

Comment: @OMEGA_F  wow!!!!!  This is great news.  Thanks so much for letting me know, it means a lot to me.  Very welcome!  Oh and thanks for picking my answer!  :-)